# how to solve this tast mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

how to x1 return back in for loop and plot xt?

```
xt = 1
x1[[1]] = xt
For[i = 2, i < 4, i++,
 xt = x1[[i - 1]];
 x1 = xt + 2;
 Print[x1]]
```

> I tried but did get results.
> Part::partd: Part specification x1[[1]] is longer than depth of object.
> "Further output of !(*StyleBox[RowBox[{"$RecursionLimit", 
> "::", "reclim2"}], "MessageName"]) will be suppressed during 
> this calculation"

Comment: Try `x1={5,4,3,2};xt=1;x1[[1]]=xt;For[i=2,i<4,i++,xt=x1[[i-1]];x1[[i]]=xt+2;Print[x1]]` which prints {1,3,3,2} and then {1,3,5,2}. Please explain step by step exactly what you are trying to do. If you can get me to understand what you want then perhaps I can explain how you can do that.

Comment: I used your code for my big tast, but did get results.

Answer (score 0):

I used your code for my big tast, but did get results.

```
 n = 4;k = 9 e9; qa = 1 e - 4;qb = 0;c = 10;r = 1;l = 20;x = 10;y = 10; angle0 = 0;T_end = 10;run = 0;beta = ArcTan[x, y];OA = l/2;OB = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]
phi1[phi_] := ((k*qa*
      qb/((Sqrt[OA^2 + OB^2 - 2*OA*OB*Cos (beta + phi)])^2*
         OA*(OB/(Sqrt[OA^2 + OB^2 - 2*OA*OB*Cos (beta + phi)]))*
         Sin[beta + phi]) - c*phi))/r
xt = angle0;yt = 0.01;tt = N@Subdivide[0, c, n]
x1 = {1, 1, 1, 1,};y1 = {1, 1, 1, 1};x1[[1]] = xt;y1[[1]] = yt;
dt = tt[[2]] - tt[[1]];
For[i = 2, i < 101, i++, xt = x1[[i - 1]];yt = y1[[i - 1]]; kx1 = dt*yt;ky1 = dt*phi1[xt];kx2 = dt*(yt + ky1);ky2 = dt*phi1[(xt + kx1)];
 x1[[i]] = xt*(kx1 + kx2)/2;y1[[i]] = xt*(ky1 + ky2)/2;]
```

Comment: Use `k=9*10^9` not `k=9 e9`. Use `Tend` not `T_end`. Use `Cos[beta+phi]` not `Cos(beta+phi)`. Please make those changes to your code above and restart Mathematica and see if it works. If it does not work then show your new code and what the result is and what the result should be.

Comment: I replaced code with your instructions. but code dit not work.phi1[phi_] := ((k*qa*
      qb/((Sqrt[OA^2 + OB^2 - 2*OA*OB*Cos [beta + phi]])^2*
         OA*(OB/(Sqrt[OA^2 + OB^2 - 2*OA*OB*Cos [beta + phi]]))*
         Sin[beta + phi]) - c*phi))/r
xt = angle0; yt = 0.01; tt = N@Subdivide[0, c, n]
x1 = {1, 1, 1, 1}; y1 = {1, 1, 1, 1}; x1[[1]] = xt; y1[[1]] = yt;
dt = tt[[2]] - tt[[1]];
For[i = 2, i < 101, i++, xt = x1[[i - 1]]; yt = y1[[i - 1]]; 
 kx1 = dt*yt; ky1 = dt*phi1[xt]; kx2 = dt*(yt + ky1); 
 ky2 = dt*phi1[(xt + kx1)];
 x1[[i]] = xt*(kx1 + kx2)/2; y1[[i]] = xt*(ky1 + ky2)/2;]

Comment: `x1=Table[0,{101}];x1[[1]]=1;x1[[2]]=1;x1[[3]]=1;x1[[4]]=1;...For[i=2,i<101,i++,...` That will let you store numbers in `x1[[5]]...x1[[101]]` Same for `y1`